# NGINX Wordpress REST API not working with allow/deny in location block

Tags: nginx, http, wordpress, http-headers

I'm trying to restrict access to a WordPress REST API with NGINX (it's the main backend `server {}` block, no proxy):

```
location ~ ^/wp-json/ {
    allow x.x.x.x;
    deny all;
}
```

The problem is, that WordPress always returns a `404` when trying to access an API endpoint (`www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages` e.g.) with that configuration (no matter if it is the browser, which is passing all Cookies and Authorization stuff, or `cURL`):

```
curl -X GET -Ik https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies
HTTP/2 404
date: Thu, 17 Jan 2019 12:40:12 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
x-robots-tag: noindex
x-content-type-options: nosniff
access-control-expose-headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, Content-Type
```

But once I comment out the `location` block, I get no errors when I access the site with a browser.

I'm afraid that happens because I need to pass some HTTP headers for authorization purposes, as I have these HTTP headers in my REQUEST (checked with chrome devtools):

```
:authority: www.example.com
:method: GET
:path: /wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies?context=edit&lang=en&_locale=user
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, */*;q=0.1
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
(!) ---> authorization: Basic crf344...fdfs334
cache-control: no-cache
(!) ---> cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_282...7da; wp-settings-1=mfo...off; wp-settings-time-1=1547726728
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://www.example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=193&action=edit
(!) ---> x-wp-nonce: df238g3ds2
```

Could someone help me please in order to configure the `location` block properly for the WordPress REST API?

EDIT:

I managed to get a `200` with `cURL` if I add the corresponding HTTP headers:

```
curl -X GET -H "authorization: Basic c2F...TVY" \
     -H "cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+...7da; \
                 wp-settings-1=mfo...off; \
                 wp-settings-time-1=1547726728"
     -H "x-wp-nonce: df238g3ds2" \
     -H "referer: https://www.example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=193&action=edit" \
     -I https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages
```

How could I do the same with the NGINX `location` block?

Comment: Why do you use `location ~ ^/wp-json/ {`  instead of simply `location /wp-json/ {` ? No need to perform regex with that string (it is slower). Also, have you double checked in logs that the IP you are allowing is the same as the one you are using to reach the site?

Comment: @NuTTyX yes I checked the IP. Even if I delete all `allow` and `deny` statements I get a `404`, if the block is commented out, it works. Thanks for your hint regarding the regex :)

Comment: Now that I think of it, you must have some directive to translate the _short and readable_ uri into the proper php file in the wordpress. Check in other locations for parameters like `try_files` and try to replicate them inside your new location directive.

Comment: @NuTTyX yes, thank you! I missed a `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`. Post it as an answer, I want to give you some points! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you requested, I'm posting my comments as an answer:

Instead of using regex (which could be a little slower) you could use a simple location.
Also, since the logic to redirect the *"pretty" permalinks* to the correct PHP file is inside another location directive, you need to copy it to your new custom location:

```
location /wp-json/ {
    allow x.x.x.x;
    deny all;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

NOTE: you might need to adjust the actual `try_files` location